# moving back and forward in a 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

disclaimer: I am a novice programmer and  I am not looking for someone to write my code for me.   I am looking for pointers or examples that I can modify to fit my needs.    How else will I learn if someone does all the work for me. :=)

Problem:  I have a 2d array that looks like the following:

```
var myArray = [["pat",  "tom" , "john"], ["sam", "toby", "barbra"],["william","jack", "janice"]];
```

I need to move through the array from one row to the next. (I will be making changes to the row.  I have already written that code and it works).

I found the following piece of code and it should allow me to move through the array.  move forward(next row), back(previous row) and current place.

```
var iterifyArr = function (arr) {
var cur = 0;
arr.nextRecord = (function () { return (++cur >= this.length) ? false : this[cur]; });// move to the next row of array
arr.prevRecord = (function () { return (--cur <= this.length) ? false : this[cur]; });//move to previous row of array
arr.cur = (function () { return this[cur]; });
return arr;
};
var myArray = [["pat",  "tom" , "john"], ["sam", "toby", "barbra"],["william","jack", "janice"]];
iterifyArr(myArray);
```

When I try to get the current position  using the following code I get the last position of the row not the row number itself.

```
var currentpos = myStack.cur();
```

Can someone please point me to where I am going wrong on this?

Comment: what should happen with the `curr` index if the index gets out of range? stay inside, stay outside, keeping the value valid?

Comment: As you're a novice, I'd recommend against using this piece of code. It tries to make things easier, but that is misleading. The `cur` variable is hidden and there's no way to get it using this exact code. What you can get is the current row, that is, the `row that has the index cur`. Try to write your own code, creating your own variables, incrementing them, using loops, etc.

Comment: I don't understand what do you want, please add expected result.

Comment: Your `arr.cur()` is returning the row on the current index, if you need the index change the function to return `cur` instead of `this[cur]`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to keep `cur`, which I renamed to `index` at a valid place. This means check before increasing or decreasing.

```js
function iterifyArr(arr) {
    var index = 0;

    arr.nextRecord = function () {
        return index + 1 < this.length && this[++index];
    };

    arr.prevRecord = function () {
        return index >= 1 && this[--index];
    };

    arr.currentRecord = function () {
        return this[index];
    };

    arr.getIndex = function () {
        return index;
    };

    return arr;
};

var myArray = [["pat", "tom", "john"], ["sam", "toby", "barbra"], ["william", "jack", "janice"]];
iterifyArr(myArray);

console.log(myArray.nextRecord());
console.log(myArray.nextRecord());
console.log(myArray.nextRecord());
console.log(myArray.currentRecord());
console.log(myArray.getIndex());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I like the way you use the `.as-console-wrapper ` in most of your answers :)

Comment: @Reddy, i just add it ... if it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The "how to think about it" questions are the ones I like the most, so pardon the verbosity.

Whenever I set up something like this, I first try to do it in a really naive way, independent of details that aren't actually part of the logic (like the language). If you start by clearly understanding the problem, you will be in a better position to identify useful code samples when you're ready to implement.

Let's clarify "rows" in terms of a 2d grid. You offer this code:

```
var myArray = [["pat",  "tom" , "john"], ["sam", "toby", "barbra"],
               ["william","jack", "janice"]];
```

Let's boil that down. g is "grid", r is "row", c is "column":

```
g = r1 ( c1, c2, c3 )
    r2 ( c1, c2, c3 )
    r3 ( c1, c2, c3 )
```

Pretty easy to see what's going on there. Then you say, "move forward through the rows". I take that to mean that you want to start with a given row, then go forward or back to the next/previous row (note that ES6 has some interesting ways of doing this sort of thing without add-on libs, "iterators").

Some very naive code sketching here (there are more functional/elegant ways of doing this, but again that's implementation details and I'm not sure of your overall familiarity with JS):

```
// let's assume first you need to find a row in your grid by a value.
// Note we just need the index of the row, not the row itself.
// You could skip this for first/last row, since 
// first would just be 0, last would be grid.length - 1
var findRow = function ( val ) {
   grid.forEach ( function ( row, row_i ) {
      if ( row.find ( val ) { 
         return row_i;
      }
   }
}

// now navigate through rows
// we will use 0 and 1 as valid vals for "next" and "previous"
// You could also add "next" and "prev" functions that just feed
// this function 0 and 1, etc.
var navRow = function ( row_num, direction ) {
  // guard against a bad direction
  var validDirections = [ 0, 1 ];
  if ( ! validDirections.find ( direction ) ) {
     console.log ( 'bad direction!!!' ) {
     return;
  }

  // guard against an out-of-bounds row number
  if ( ! (row_num >= 0 && row_num < grid.length) ) {
    console.log ( 'bad row num!!!' );
    return;
  }

  // if all that checks out, compute the target row.
  // note that we allow for wrapping.
  // direction is either 0 or 1, so we can just use a falsy check
  if ( direction ) {
     row_num++; 
  } else {
     row_num--;
  }

  // check to make sure the new row number isn't out of bounds,
  // if it is, wrap it
  if ( row_num < 0 ) {
     row_num = grid.length - 1;
  } else if ( row_num >= grid.length ) {
     row_num = 0;
  }

  // return the index 
  return row_num;
}
```

Now to use:

```
var startIndex = findRow ( 'janice' );
// Note that startIndex may be undefined if no row is found!
// Will assume you guard against that.
var newIndex = navRow ( startRow, 0 ); // go back, or wrap to end
var newIndex = navRow ( startRow, 1 ); // forward, or wrap to start
```

Your start row was grid [ start_index ], your newly nav'd row is now grid [ newIndex ]

Note that by doing it this way, you avoid having to use class or global level vars to track the index as you continue to navigate. newIndex just becomes your startIndex (hmm...recursion...generator/yield? Interesting...). Anyway, that's good.

Again, pretty naive, but by now you're probably seeing the principals involved in moving around a simple grid, and can probably set the code up yourself.

Note: this code assumes a VERY naive grid. If your grid can look like this (note non unique row vals, duplicates, uneven rows, etc):

```
[ [ undefined, 0, '' ], undefined, [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ] ];
```

Then you have some more work and testing to do (though the above code should still pretty much do the trick more or less). Just sketch it out first, check your logic and guards, THEN go to the code.